# Why do these arrays work when they are local, but not when they are global?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++/programming in general so I have been experimenting to see what I can and can't do and I've come across something that seems like it should be working, but isn't. For some reason, when I place the two arrays outside of any functions to make them public they do not work as if they were public.

When I place both of them inside my main function the code works perfectly fine, but I want to be able to use them for other functions as well. Is there something wrong with the way I wrote it or will I need to put both arrays in every function I want them to work in?

edit: Expected behavior is to input a number 1-9 and receive a letter a-i, then on another line change the letter to X. When the arrays are placed outside of the function I want them to work in, none of the letters a-i are shown and it skips the line and outputs X. When placed inside, if I were for example to type in 4, "d" would output and then "X" on the next line.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char pos[3][3] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'};
char pos2[] = {pos[3][3]};
char player = 'X';

int main()
{
    int a;

    for (int i = 0; true; i++)
    {
    cin >> a;
    cout << pos2[a] << endl;

    pos2[a] = player;

    cout << pos2[a] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are indexed from `0`. If you declare an array with 3 elements (such as `pos[3]`) you can access 0, 1 and 2 - accessing `3` is out of bounds and undefined behaviour

Comment: Unrelated: if you wish to have an infinite loop like you do, you can simply write `for (;;)`

Comment: Yes, there are two limits to the quantity of arrays you can have.  The first limit is the amount of memory that your OS grants your program.  The other limit is the width of the `size_t` or `pointer` sizes.  For example, you will be able to have less arrays on a 16-bit address system than a system that uses 64-bits for addressing.

Comment: Beware of buffer overrun.  If you have an array of size 3 (three elements), writing 6 elements is undefined behavior.  There is no guarantee that there will be memory after the 3rd slot.  Also, the compiler may place other variables next to your array, so that if you go beyond the array bounds, you would be overwriting other variables (and possibly executable code).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Is there any way to see the limit of my program? I'm using CodeBlocks.

Comment: @user2864740 I apologize, it was poor wording. I mean when I try to use the array inside a function, if declared inside that function it works as intended. To my knowledge, placing the arrays outside of a function makes them public in C++, yet when I try to use them in a function without them being declared the function does not work as intended. I edited my original post to explain more in detail of the expected behavior.

Comment: The memory size limit is not set by your IDE.  The limit is set by your operating system or platform.  Often, compilers will set the limits for you, based on your operating system or platform.  With modern desktop computers, I have yet to exceed the memory allocations set by the compiler.

Comment: The title was entirely *irrelevant* to the ask/problem in the body. **Unfortunately, the clarification change invalidates most comments above.** The only way such “maximum number of global arrays” *might* have been relevant was if the answer was something like “no more than 1 is allowed”, which is clearly ridiculous.

Comment: When declaring arrays inside a function, you can have them use "local" memory (e.g. stack) or you can have them use automatic (global) memory.  If you prefix the array declaration with `static`, the array will be placed into a different memory area that has more capacity.

Comment: Commonly, programs have less "stack" memory than global or dynamic (heap) memory.  According to the C++ language, memory areas are designated based on *lifetime*.  The local (stack) memory is primarily for variables that have short lifetimes (like within loops or functions).  Global variable area is for variables that will have a lifetime of the entire program.  The dynamic area, e.g. heap, is for variables that can't be allocated during compile time.  Often, the dynamic area is larger than the global area of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pos2` array only has one element. Accessing any element other than `pos2[0]` is Undefined Behavior. That means your program can crash, or it may appear to work perfectly.

Since you're trying to access 9 elements in the array, you should declare it as

```
char pos2[9] = {pos[3][3]};
```

preferably with some named constant instead of the hard-coded 9. This will create a 9 element array, with the first element initialized to the character `'i'` and the other 8 set to 0.

Since you don't have any error checking on your input, there is a good chance of bad behavior if the user doesn't input a number in the range `[0..8]`. (`pos[9]` is out-of-bounds.) To adjust this to the range [`1..9`], you need to subtract 1 during indexing:

```
cout << pos2[a - 1] << endl;
// (also other references to `pos2[a]`)
```

or decrement `a` by 1 before using as the subscript.